# How to get the last element of an array in Angular2 template WITHOUT LOOPING EVERYTHING?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

**This question is not asking how to get access to looping variables like i, first, last but how to retrieve and set variable as TEMPLATE VARIABLES.**

---

This is not working...

```
<div #lastElement="arr[arr.length-1]"></div>
```

So I actually need to create a local variable in component then bind it directly?

I feel lots of stuff I can do it with ng-* directives in the past are all required to hardcode in Component... Kind of degrading tbh

Comment: That should work, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: My suspicion is you are getting an undefined error due to the component binding before the data is ready. You might need to use a ternary to get around this. `#lastElement="!!arr && arr.length > 0 ? arr[arr.length-1] : undefined"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on why you need this. Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: There is a list of social media icons, but only the last one requires a few more directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign arbitrary values to template variables. Template variables are for references to elements and directives and locals used for structural directives.

Answer (score 16):

You can use boolean keyword `last`, here in this example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let last = last;let first = first;let index = index">
first:{{first}}
index:{{index}}
last:{{last}}
</div>
```

result:

```
first:true index:0 last:false
first:false index:1 last:false
first:false index:2 last:false
first:false index:3 last:true
```

Comment: The question is to do it without looping everything. My answer below should be the correct answer.

Comment: @JoshuaSzuslik You are looping too

Answer (score 1):

You would set the `lastelement` variable in your template loop. Angular will automatically bind the last element in your loop to the last directive.

```
<div *ngFor="#item of items; #lastElement = last">
   // Items go here
</div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html